# ¿A qué se debe este error al registrar en PostgreSQL?

Tags: laravel-5, postgresql

estoy desarrollando una app en Laravel 5.5, estoy usando como gestor de base de datos PostgreSQL, al momento de hacer un registro me muestra el siguiente error:

> "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input
>   syntax for integer: "jorge@gmail.com" (SQL: select count(*) as
>   aggregate from "shoppers" where "id" = jorge@gmail.com and "id" <> )"

**El código de mi controlador:**

```
public function store(ShopperRequest $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax()){
            $this->formatoCadena($request);
            $request['nivel'] = $this->calcularNivel($request);
            if($shopper = Shopper::create($request->all())){
                if($shopper->shopperEstudio()->create($request->all())){
                return response()->json('Exito');
                }else{
                    return response()->json('Error');
                }
            }else{
                return response()->json('Error');
            }
        }
    }
```

**El código de mi modelo:**

```
protected $table = 'shoppers';
protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'apellido', 'sexo', 'estado_civil', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'hijos', 'estado_id', 'municipio_id', 'colonia_id', 'correo', 'tendencia_alimenticia', 'consume_alcohol', 'banco', 'cuenta_deposito', 'nivel', 'status', 'read_at'];
public $timestamps = true;
```

**El código de la migración:**

```
class CreateShoppersTable extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        Schema::create('shoppers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre', 25);
            $table->string('apellido', 25); 
            $table->enum('sexo', ['Masculino', 'Femenino']);
            $table->date('fecha_nacimiento');
            $table->enum('estado_civil', ['Soltero/a', 'Comprometido/a', 'Casado/a', 'Divorciado/a', 'Viudo/a']);
            $table->boolean('hijos');
            $table->integer('estado_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('municipio_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('colonia_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('correo', 80);
            $table->enum('tendencia_alimenticia', ['Omnivoros', 'Vegano', 'Vegetariano', 'No consume cerdo']);
            $table->boolean('consume_alcohol');
            $table->enum('banco', ['CitiBanamex', 'BBVA Bancomer', 'HSBC', 'Scotiabank', 'Santander', 'Banorte', 'Inbursa', 'Banco del bajío', 'Bansi', 'Afirme', 'Banco Azteca', 'Otro']);
            $table->string('otro_banco', 25)->nullable();
            $table->string('cuenta_deposito', 20);
            $table->enum('status', ['Pendiente', 'Activo', 'Inactivo']);
            $table->enum('nivel', ['E', 'D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'A/B']);
            $table->dateTime('read_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('estado_id')->references('id')->on('estados');
            $table->foreign('municipio_id')->references('id')->on('municipios');
            $table->foreign('colonia_id')->references('id')->on('colonias');
        });
    }

    public function down(){
        Schema::dropIfExists('shoppers');
    }
}
```

**Vista del formulario (La parte que manda los datos):**

```
function registroShopper(){
            var route = '/shoppers/registro';
            var token = $('#token').val();
            var datos = {
                'nombre': $('#nombre').val(),
                'apellido': $('#apellido').val(),
                'sexo': $('input[name=sexo]:checked').val(),
                'fecha_nacimiento': $('#fecha_nacimiento').val(),
                'estado_civil': $('#estado_civil').val(),
                'hijos': $('input[name=hijos]:checked').val(),
                'estado_id': $('#estado_id').val(),
                'municipio_id': $('#municipio_id').val(),
                'colonia_id': $('#colonia_id').val(),
                'correo': $('#correo').val(),

                'tendencia_alimenticia': $('#tendencia_alimenticia').val(),
                'consume_alcohol': $('input[name=consume_alcohol]:checked').val(),

                'p1': $('#p1').val(),
                'p2': $('#p2').val(),
                'p3': $('#p3').val(),
                'p4': $('input[name=p4]:checked').val(),
                'p5': $('#p5').val(),
                'p6': $('#p6').val(),

                'banco': $('#banco').val(),
                'otro_banco': null,
                'cuenta_deposito': $('#cuenta_deposito').val(),

                'status': $('#status').val(),
                'telefono': $('#telefono').val(),
            };

            if(otro_banco)
                datos.otro_banco = $('#otro_banco').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: route,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: datos,
            }).done(function(response){
                if(response == "Exito"){
                    var $toastContent = $('<ul>El shopper ha sido registrado.</ul>').add($('<button type="button" class="btn-flat toast-action white-text" id="cerrar-toast" onclick="cerrarToast()";><i class="material-icons">close</i></button>'));
                    Materialize.toast($toastContent, 10000000, 'green');
                }else if(response == "Error"){
                    $.each(response, function(i, val){
                        Materialize.toast(val, 4000, 'red');
                    });
                }
            }).fail(function(response){
                listarErrores(response.responseJSON.errors);
            });
        }
```

**ShopperRequest:**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre' => 'required|max:25|unique_with:shoppers,[apellido, estado_id, municipio_id, colonia_id,],'.$this->get('id'),
            'apellido' => 'required|max:25',
            'sexo' => 'required',
            'fecha_nacimiento' => 'required',
            'estado_civil' => 'required',
            'hijos' => 'required',
            'estado_id' => 'required',
            'municipio_id' => 'required',
            'colonia_id' => 'required',
            'correo' => 'email|required|max:80|unique:shoppers,'.$this->get('id'),
            'tendencia_alimenticia' => 'required',
            'consume_alcohol' => 'required',
            'banco' => 'required',
            'otro_banco' => 'required_if:banco,Otro',
            'cuenta_deposito' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'p1' => 'required',
            'p2' => 'required',
            'p3' => 'required',
            'p4' => 'required',
            'p5' => 'required',
            'p6' => 'required',
            //
        ];
    }
```

Este error se muestra al querer registrar el correo.

Comment: Según eso estás utilizando el correo como id, el cual es un integer. Podría ser interesante ver el código de la vista del formulario y el de  ShopperRequest.

Comment: Listo @Shaz, ya agregue esa parte

Comment: ¿Asumo que estás usando tu validación personalizada o un paquete para `unique_with`?

Comment: Si, estoy usando un paquete para usar esa validaciòn